# How to return two values in Python

Tags: python, return-value

I have following code below.

```
class NameParser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.getName

    def getName(self, name):
        splitName = name.split(' ')
        surname = splitName.pop()
        for i in range(len(splitName)):
            print('Name: %s' % splitName[i])

        return('Surname: %s' % surname)


np = NameParser()

print(np.getName("ali opcode goren"))

# output: name: ali, name: opcode, surname: goren
```

How do i return two values? Like following code:

```
for i in range(len(splitName)):
    return('Name: %s' % splitName[i])

return('Surname: %s' % surname)

# output: name ali: (error) i want all values name, name, surname
```

I want all values but just one output. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Not expected.

Output for two return: ali goren.

Output for one print and one return: ali opcode goren (i want this)

Comment: `return "Name: %s, Name: %s, Surname: %s"%(splitName[0], splitName[1], splitName[2])` and need to do exception handling when some name is missing in the input string.

Comment: or just return split list `return splitName`

Comment: @VivekSable thanks but this is manual. i want automatic. example:

abc cb cde ffe ags dle like => split[0,1,2,3,4]. but your code not automatic. thanks for your help.

Comment: just assign string variable before for loop `output=""` and iterate for loop and concatenate output in the for loop like `output = "%s Name %s,"%(output, splitname[i])` and last after for loop do  `output = "%s Surname %s,"%(output, surname)` and return output

Comment: no nee to iterate for loop by range method. we can use `for i in splitName:` also in `i` is item from the list.

Comment: @VivekSable this is not true.... I knew it already, but I tried it again still not possible.

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel: what is not possible?

Comment: @vivekSable This is not possible   'for i in splitName: '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class NameParser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.getName

    def getName(self, name):
        listy = [] # where the needed output is put in
        splitName = name.split(' ')

        for i in range(len(splitName)):
            if i==(len(splitName)-1):#when the last word is reach
                listy.append('Surname: '+ splitName[i])
            else:
              listy.append('Name: '+ splitName[i])


        return listy


nr = NameParser()

print(nr.getName("ali opcode goren"))

# output: name: ali, name: opcode, surname: goren
```

whithout loop:

```
class NameParser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.getName

    def getName(self, name):
        listy = [] # where the needed output is put in
        splitName = name.split(" ")
        listy ="Name",splitName[0],"Name",splitName[1],"Surname",splitName[2]



        return listy


nr = NameParser()

print(nr.getName("ali opcode goren"))

# output: name: ali, name: opcode, surname: goren
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Not working.

Just output: Name: ali

I want like: Name: ali, Name: opcode, Surname: goren

if i use print, it's work.

Comment: Thanks i get "goren" :). I can't get other values. I can solve, I guess.

Comment: I add  also another code for when you don't want a loop. You ask it in another comment.

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel: in second code why you define `listy = []` ? need this statement?

Comment: You always have to declare a list how big he will be. So to say he is empty in my code he will be declared. When you want to fill the list, use append this will add a *something what you want* to the list

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel: Second code: what is type of `listy` variable?

Comment: @VivekSable that is a list

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel: just print type of this variable. `print type(listy)` before return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76188/discussion-between-vivek-sable-and-martijn-van-wezel).

Answer (score 3):

1. **Split**: Split name by space and then do **list comprehension** again to remove the empty string from the list.
2. **POP**: get last item from the list by `pop()` method and assign it to `surname` variable.
3. **Exception Handling**: Do exception handling during pop process. If the  input is empty then this will raise an `IndexError` exception.
4. **string concatenate**: Iterate every Item from the list by `for loop` and assign the value to `user_name` variable.
5. Concatenate `surname` in string again.
6. Display result.

**Demo**:

```
class NameParser:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getName(self, name):
        #- Spit name and again check for empty strings.
        splitName = [i.strip() for i in name.split(' ') if i.strip()]
        #- Get Surname. 
        try:
            surname = splitName.pop()
        except IndexError:
            print "Exception Name for processing in empty."
            return ""
        user_name = ""
        for i in splitName:
            user_name = "%s Name: %s,"%(user_name, i)
        user_name = user_name.strip()

        user_name = "%s Surname: %s"%(user_name, surname)
        return user_name


np = NameParser()
user_name = np.getName("ali      opcode       goren      abc")
print "user_name:", user_name
```

**Output**:

```
user_name: Name: ali, Name: opcode, Name: goren, Surname: abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `yield`

```
class NameParser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.getName

    def getName(self, name):
        splitName = name.split(' ')
        surname = splitName.pop()
        for i in range(len(splitName)):
            yield ('Name: %s' % splitName[i])

        yield ('Surname: %s' % surname)


np = NameParser()

for i in (np.getName("ali opcode goren")):
    print i
```

Comment: Thanks it's work! :) How to use this code without your for loop?

Comment: Read [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python). Ali, to learn about `yield`.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this:

```
def getName(self, name):
    return name.split(' ')
```

It will return a tuple

```
def get_name(name):
   return name.split(' ')

>>> get_name("First Middle Last")
['First', 'Middle', 'Last']
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try

```
class test():
    map = {}
    for i in range(10):
        map[f'{i}'] = i
    return map
```